# How to make a table to organize buttons in PHP

Tags: php, html, tabular

I  have this code which creates buttons from files in a directory.  I need to organize them in a table with 4 columns.  How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
$handle = opendir('mydirectory');

if($handle){
    while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && $entry != '.htaccess'){

       echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='mydirectory/$entry'\"    style=\"background-color: #660000;\"><p style=color:white;>$entry</button><br>";

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

Comment: If you insist using `<table>`, there will be a lot of `<tr><td>` codes. Instead, I suggest you use CSS `float: left` to let browser auto arrange your buttons instead.

Comment: @Raptor: That could probably be the kernel of a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what @Raptor mentioned in the comments you could do something like this:

```
<style>
#buttons{
  width: 300px;
  float:left;
}
</style>
<div id="buttons">
<?php
for($i=0;$i <=10; $i++){
  echo "<button>Button $i</button>";
}
?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You just have to set the CSS .

Comment: This is exactly how I want my buttons to be organized. Thank You. I do have one problem with this though, my buttons are different sizes and I want them to be organized so there is a little bit of space between them so that they can be aligned. How can I do this?

Comment: @Alchemist - `margin-right:5px;` css style on button?